# Android studio Manifest and Gradle files destroyed after my pc shut down suddenly

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I was working on a project. Maybe for electricity drop my pc restarted and now my Manifest & Gradle file text like alien..:(

here is some screenshots :
[image: Manifest]

[image: Gradle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

- Copy the whole project folder ,
- then paste anywhere you want ,
- then just open this new pasted project from Android Studio

I've solved my alien texts by this way.